# wp_delete_user function to delete the user from front end is not working

Tags: wordpress

I am working on a wordpress site. When a user login to the site, he is redirected to terms and conditions page. So if he accept terms and conditions, he will be allowed to use services and if he don't accept terms and conditions, his account will be terminated. Now I used the wp_delete_user function in order to terminate his account but its not working. Here is my code

```
add_action('init', 'function_init_terms');

function function_init_terms()
{
    if(isset($_POST['terms_submit']))
    {
        if($_POST['terms_agree'] == 'yes')
        {
            wp_redirect( get_permalink(215)); exit;
        }
        if($_POST['terms_agree'] != 'yes')
        {

            $user_ID = get_current_user_id();

             wp_delete_user($user_ID);
                echo html_entity_decode( wp_logout_url(home_url()) );




        }
    }
}
```

The first part of the code is working fine i.e if he is agreed with terms and conditions, he is redirected to page id 215 successfully. But the other part is not working. Here is my html

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php bloginfo('url') ?>/">
 <input type="checkbox" name="terms_agree" id="terms_agree" value="yes"/>Agree<br>
 <input type="submit" name="terms_submit" id="terms_submit" value="Continue" />
 </form>
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'the other part is not working'? Do you get any error?

Comment: because when user doesn't accept the terms and conditions, his account should be terminated but it redirects to the home page and user is still logged in and his account is not deleted.

Comment: have done it. used global variable $wpdb. thanks for your time

Comment: It can be done with `wp_delete_user`. You must include the `./wp-admin/includes/user.php` file before the `wp_delete_user()` function call, otherwise it will throw a `call to undefined function` error. Example here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_delete_user#Examples

Answer (score 12):

To make this post more readable for googlers, the answer from [Adreivictor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22734910/wp-delete-user-function-to-delete-the-user-from-front-end-is-not-working#comment34651229_22734910):

To use the back-end function `wp_delete_user()`, you need to `require_once(ABSPATH.'wp-admin/includes/user.php' );`

Example from Wordpress:

```
if(is_user_logged_in() && !empty($_GET['DeleteMyAccount'])) {
    add_action('init', 'remove_logged_in_user');
}

function remove_logged_in_user() {
    require_once(ABSPATH.'wp-admin/includes/user.php' );
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    wp_delete_user( $current_user->ID );
}
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_delete_user#Examples